# SQL : How to limit query for one record?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am stuck with Limiting the record to one record per user but not able to find any solution, I am not an expert in SQL query so need some help. "FETCH FIRST ROW" is not working.

Requirement:
To get all the users from transaction table who have used the same card for payment.

I have written query which is giving me the desired result. The query is as :

```
SELECT distinct 
D1.ID, D1.CUSTOMER_ID, D1.TOKEN_VALUE FROM ORDER_DETAILS D1, ORDER_DETAILS D2
WHERE D1.TOKEN_VALUE = D2.TOKEN_VALUE AND D1.CUSTOMER_ID <> D2.CUSTOMER_ID 
ORDER BY  D1.TOKEN_VALUE desc;
```

Output for the query is as:
[image: Query Result]

**Issue** with the query is that I am getting multiple records for the same user however I would like to restrict the data to one row per user.
What modification is required in Query to restrict the data to one record for each user instead of getting all the transaction.

Comment: Remove the column ID from the select list of it is not needed.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should switch to 'modern' explicit `join` syntax, rather than comma separated join style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OD.CUSTOMER_ID, OD.TOKEN_VALUE
FROM (SELECT OD.*,
             MIN(CUSTOMER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY TOKEN_VALUE) as MIN_CUSTOMER_ID,
             MAX(CUSTOMER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY TOKEN_VALUE) as MAX_CUSTOMER_ID
      FROM ORDER_DETAILS OD
     ) OD
WHERE MIN_CUSTOMER_ID <> MAX_CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY OD.TOKEN_VALUE DESC;
```

No `JOIN` is needed.

An alternative method uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OD.CUSTOMER_ID, OD.TOKEN_VALUE
FROM ORDER_DETAILS OD
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ORDER_DETAILS OD2
              WHERE OD2.TOKEN_VALUE = OD.TOKEN_VALUE AND
                    OD2.CUSTOMER_ID <> OD.CUSTOMER_ID
             )
ORDER BY OD.TOKEN_VALUE;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the subquery use `OD2.CUSTOMER_ID <> OD.CUSTOMER_ID`?

Comment: Alternate however works fine, but the condition need to be updated OD2.CUSTOMER_ID = OD.CUSTOMER_ID to OD2.CUSTOMER_ID <> OD.CUSTOMER_ID

Answer (score 0):

If you run the same query without D1.ID you should get the result you're looking for

```
SELECT distinct 
D1.CUSTOMER_ID, D1.TOKEN_VALUE FROM ORDER_DETAILS D1, ORDER_DETAILS D2
WHERE D1.TOKEN_VALUE = D2.TOKEN_VALUE AND D1.CUSTOMER_ID <> D2.CUSTOMER_ID 
ORDER BY  D1.TOKEN_VALUE desc;
```